# CompositeController not getting `childrenJson` element when being called by kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am writing a compositecontroller to create child resources. My controller definition is as follows:

```
apiVersion: metacontroller.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: CompositeController
metadata:
  name: hive-table-controller
spec:
  generateSelector: true
  parentResource:
    apiVersion: fabrikam.com/v1
    resource: hivetables
  childResources:
  - apiVersion: v1
    resource: pods
    updateStrategy:
      method: Recreate
    conditions:
```

But when my controller is getting called, the `childrenJson` element in NULL.

I am using java.

This is my metacontroller version...

```
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/name=metacontroller
              controller-revision-hash=metacontroller-859cbfcc65
```

And the image:

```
  metacontroller:
    Container ID:  docker://ebeef897f3a7324b40c447046575ff0d948dc2c3d1023e33ca3eb5897bf8534b
    Image:         metacontroller/metacontroller:v0.4.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://metacontroller/metacontroller@sha256:ad85cb5f5ad9a61a3f38277fed371df43ea0fc55d9073dfa8f4fc2e27c127603
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to follow this example: https://metacontroller.github.io/metacontroller/guide/create.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... the JSON was not getting deserialized correctly because my object did not have a `children` field.